Identifying Visual Studio 2022 theme
What is the Visual Studio 2022 theme in the image below?

When I logout my account in VS2022 to refresh something, the theme I'm using was also reset. I have tried all installed themes one at a time yet nothing matches the last screenshot I have.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Ok I figure it out. I was the Goodnight theme then I change the font to Consolas.
